# How to find a Activerecord entry with no many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

So let's say we have a User model and it has many projects

How can I find a user who has no projects?

A very inefficient way would be to do this:

```
all_projects_with_users = Project.all.pluck(:user_id).uniq
all_users = User.all.pluck(:id)
users_without_projects = all_users - all_projects_with_users
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use a left outer join and where the join table id is null:

```
User.left_joins(:projects)
    .where(projects: { id: nil })
```

`left_outer_joins` aka `left_joins` was introduced in Rails 5. For Rails 4 you need to use a workaround:

```
User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOINS projects ON projects.user_id = users.id")
    .where(projects: { id: nil })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick solution on top of my head, hope it could help.

```rb
User.joins('left outer join projects where projects.user_id = users.id').where('projects.id is null')
```

For rails 5, you could use `left_joins`

```rb
User.left_joins(:projects).where('projects.user_id is null')
```